# Как сделать сайт мультиязычным через php + Mysql?

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Как сделать сайт мультиязычным через php + Mysqli? Контент слова хранится в БД, как сделать?

ПОСМОТРИТЕ ЗДЕСЬ:

[image]

"My `<?php echo lang('id слова'); ?>`" если я поставлю id 1 "My home" вот так можно? Мне все нужно от и до, я новичок, помогите программисты!

Comment: @Кыран Нуркелды, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: terantul спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для локализации лучше использовать готовые инструменты, например, gettext.
Но судя по прошлому вопросу вам бы сначала с основами разобраться, а уже потом локализацией заниматься.
Если надо делать срочно, то почитайте что-нить типа "PHP за 21 день" - познакомитесь с основами, двигаться дальше будет уже легче.
А про локализацию через базу можно здесь в вопросах поискать, не так давно их было несколько штук.